# How to get php database values before the values are loaded using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

So i have 3 pages. upload.php, main.php and script.js. Upload.php lists some database entries, and has a button behind each entry for more info on the entry. When you press the button it gives the ID value from the database with POST in the url and so it loads the info in main.php with the given id.

I have a javascript file: script.js which needs those db values that are echoed on main.php. I watched a tutorial on passing a variable from php to js using ajax. But the problem is that the values on main are only posted when you press the button in upload.php. Which means when i run the script it just fetches from main.php which has no values if the button is not pressed on upload.php.

How do i make the javascript get the values from main?

Im very new to js.

Comment: Not clear where your issues are. You defined the needed approach in your question ...the JS send an AJAX request to get the values. Please add code if you've tried that already and are having issues.

Comment: Hello Lucas, please provide more information on your problem and perhaps some code snipet for us to help you with. Make sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then come back to re-edit your post.

Comment: hopefully made it more clear..

Comment: First hit on google https://programmerblog.net/jquery-ajax-get-example-php-mysql/

Comment: @Grumpy i think i can use this, ty. I searched the wrong thing on google so i could not find it.

Comment: When do you run this javascript file and what do you want to do with those db values in this script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Leonard i run this script after the variables in main have been displayed. But when the script tries to acces main it has no variables because it straightup opens main without pressing the button on upload.php. I want to use the db variables to create searchqueries and open multiple browser windows with those search queries.

Comment: How does your script open the page? You likely could add a GET to the request then have the page function differently for when that parameter is there. There's no way for anyone to answer this question with the few technical details provided.

Comment: @user3783243 function doAJAX () {
  fetch("../upload.php")
  .then(result => result.text())
  .then((data) => { console.log(data); });
}

        </script>

Comment: I fixed it, made the script a php file instead of a js. Made a db connection at the beginning of the page. Assigned db values to php value $adress for example. And then set the variable in js: let name ='<?=$adress?>';

Comment: So button has `doAJAX ()` in `onclick`? Could also have something like `function doAJAX (ready = false ) { `fetch("../upload.php" + ( ready != false ? '?partial=1) : '')` then only load needed content on other page if `partial` is set.. that rough JS though, will need to modify.. and have a `document.ready` enact `doAJAX` with a value passed to it.